# How to identify why lazy spring bean was initialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot project with many beans, so I can't just use my IDE to look understand the beans dependency tree.

So given a lazy bean method, how can I see why it was initialized? I mean what other Spring bean was dependent on it and resulted in its initialization?

Comment: Throwing an exception in the lazy bean's constructor may tell you.

Comment: Tried that, you only get a Spring filled stacktrace and it doesn't say anything about who or why initiated the call

Comment: It should, it will give you the location the bean was initialized. But the interesting question is why does it matter, what is it you are trying to solve? You can just check your code base for locations this bean (or the interface it implements) is being used, or maybe it is a special type of bean (one of the spring lifecycle classes/extensions). So for starters check your code base (your IDE will help) and please add the bean/class/config in question to this question (not as comments as an edit).